# Writing a large JSON to CSV using sparklyr

Tags: r, json, csv, apache-spark

I'm trying to convert a large JSON file (6GB) into a CSV to more easily load it into R. I happened upon this solution (from https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-read-large-json-file-in-r/13486/33):

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/usr/lib/spark")
# Configure cluster (c3.4xlarge 30G 16core 320disk)
conf <- spark_config()
conf$'sparklyr.shell.executor-memory' <- "7g"
conf$'sparklyr.shell.driver-memory' <- "7g"
conf$spark.executor.cores <- 20
conf$spark.executor.memory <- "7G"
conf$spark.yarn.am.cores  <- 20
conf$spark.yarn.am.memory <- "7G"
conf$spark.executor.instances <- 20
conf$spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled <- "false"
conf$maximizeResourceAllocation <- "true"
conf$spark.default.parallelism <- 32

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = conf, version = '2.2.0')
sample_tbl <- spark_read_json(sc,name="example",path="example.json", header = TRUE, memory = FALSE,
                              overwrite = TRUE) 
sdf_schema_viewer(sample_tbl)
```

I've never used Spark before, and I'm trying to understand where the data I loaded is located in Rstudio, and how can I write the data to a CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about sparklyr, but if you are trying to read large json file and trying to write into CSV file using **Spark R**, below is sample code for same.

This code will run only on spark environment and not in Rstudio

```
# A JSON dataset is pointed to by path.
# The path can be either a single text file or a directory storing text files.
path <- "examples/src/main/resources/people.json" 
# Create a DataFrame from the file(s) pointed to by path
people <- read.json(path)
# Write date frame to CSV
write.df(people, "people.csv", "csv")
```